# Forward message bot telegram python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I use python-telegram-bot and I don't understand how forward a message from the user to a telegram group, I have something like this:

```
def feed(bot, update):
  bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="reply this message"
  bot.forward_message(chat_id="telegram group", from_chat_id="username bot", message_id=?)
```

I need to forward the message the user shares the message and the reply must be sent to a group.

How it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.forward_message):
**chat_id** - Unique identifier for the target chat ...
**from_chat_id** - Unique identifier for the ***chat where the original message was sent*** ...
**message_id** - Message identifier in the chat specified in from_chat_id.

Solution:

```
def feed(bot, update):
    # send reply to the user
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                     text='reply this message')
    # forward user message to group
    # note: group ID with the negative sign
    bot.forward_message(chat_id='-1010101001010',
                        from_chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=update.message.message_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy with `Telethon`.

You need the `chat_id`, `from_chat_id`.

You can add a bot and you will need the token.